# Listview shows images in wrong positions when scrolling

Tags: android, image, listview, android-asynctask

I have a ListView which I am filling from server. Everything works fine but the single problem is that the downloaded images are shown in wrong item positions when scroll. Only after a few seconds then it shows the correct image on the right position.

Here is my ArrayAdapter class, which includes the AsynchTask:

```
public class ApplicationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Application> {
    private List<Application> items;

    public ApplicationAdapter(Context context, List<Application> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.app_custom_list, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.app_custom_list, null);
        }

        Application app = items.get(position);

        if (app != null) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.appIcon);
            TextView titleText  = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titleTxt);

            if (imageView != null) {

                String path_image = app.getImagePath();

                // Call AsynchTask to load image into ImageView from path
                DownloadImageTask1 d = new DownloadImageTask(imageView);
                d.execute(path_image);
            }


            if (titleText != null) {

                titleText.setText(app.getTitle());

            }

        }

        return v;
    }

private class DownloadImageTask1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask1(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerBitmap(result));

    }
}
```

Can somebody please guide me to the right direction? I am already working for days to solve this issue. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the `ImageView` is reused when the `listview` is scrolled. show a loading image in the `listview` `onPreExecute`. it woluld be better if you use some library like [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for this. as it does all the work for you including saving the image in the catch

Comment: Thank you very much. I am now using Picasso and it works awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You should use another class for holding your objects, it helps you keep a good reference once set.

And it's best you change your adapter a little bit.

It's best you get a reference to your layoutInflater once , since getView is called for every item in the listview.

So declare your layoutInflater for the whole class and get a reference only once

For example :

```
 private LayoutInflater inflater;


 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageHolder holder = new ImageHolder();

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_item_transition, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appIcon);
            TextView titleText  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleTxt);
            holder.image = imageView;
            holder.title = titleText;
            convertView.setTag(holder); 

        }else{
            holder = (ImageHolder) convertView.getTag(position);
        }

        Application app = items.get(position);

        if (app != null) {


            holder.title.seText(app.getTitle());
            String path_image = app.getImagePath();

            // Call AsynchTask to load image into ImageView from path
            DownloadImageTask1 d = new DownloadImageTask1(holder.imageView);

            d.execute(path_image);
        }

        return convertView;
    }


    private static class ImageHolder{
        ImageView image;
        TextView title;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) library to load images.. Try this

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, holder.imgView, options);
```

to load images inside adapter..

Use DisplayImageOptions as follows inside constructor of adapter

```
 options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(android.R.color.transparent)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(android.R.color.transparent)
                .showImageOnFail(android.R.color.transparent)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .build();
```

and add

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

inside onCreateView/onCreate of fragment/activity contaning the list

Comment: Are there huge differences between picasso and universalimageloader lib?

Comment: @Sini Not huge differences..UniversalImageLoader is highly customizable and is better in  documentation and provides flexible ways you can load a bitmap or image..... To know detailed differences check this link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995007/local-image-caching-solution-for-android-square-picasso-vs-universal-image-load.. You can +one my answer if you find it useful..Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
replace

 if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.app_custom_list, null);
        }

with

if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.app_custom_list, null);
            convertView.setTag(v);
        } else {
            v = (View) convertView.getTag();
        }
```