# Comparison of Image Library for Android (Picasso, Fresco, etc.)

Tags: android, out-of-memory, imagelibrary

Does anyone make a comparison about the Image-library for android ?

Handling images in Android sometimes is a headache since it's always about the memory problem. There are some popular libs also (such as `Picasso`, `Fresco`), having been playing some of those, anyone did some comparison before ?

Comment: Look at this SO post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Picasso v/s Imageloader v/s Fresco vs Glide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to this:

https://twitter.com/jessewilson/status/581235604740042752

[Local image caching solution for Android: Square Picasso vs Universal Image Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995007/local-image-caching-solution-for-android-square-picasso-vs-universal-image-load)

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/solving-the-android-image-loading-problem-volley-vs-picasso/

[Android Image loading - Volley vs Picasso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782122/android-image-loading-volley-vs-picasso)

[Picasso v/s Imageloader v/s Fresco vs Glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide)