# OutOfMemoryError When Apply Some effect filter on image

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, image-processing, out-of-memory

i am going to make app like **Retrica**

The problem is that i am apply some filter or effect on image it will cause java.lang.OutOfMemoryError and take a more time to apply on image.

```
public class ImageEnhancemeane extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int[] FROM_COLOR = new int[]{49, 179, 110};
    private static final int THRESHOLD = 3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_enhancemeane);

        ImageView imgStatus = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backImage);
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.testimg);

        imgStatus.setImageBitmap(createSepiaToningEffect(bm, 2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.59));

    }

    public static Bitmap createSepiaToningEffect(Bitmap src, int depth, double red, double green, double blue) {
        // image size
        int width = src.getWidth();
        int height = src.getHeight();
        // create output bitmap
        Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, src.getConfig());
        // constant grayscale
        final double GS_RED = 0.3;
        final double GS_GREEN = 0.59;
        final double GS_BLUE = 0.11;
        // color information
        int A, R, G, B;
        int pixel;

        // scan through all pixels
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
                // get pixel color
                pixel = src.getPixel(x, y);
                // get color on each channel
                A = Color.alpha(pixel);
                R = Color.red(pixel);
                G = Color.green(pixel);
                B = Color.blue(pixel);
                // apply grayscale sample
                B = G = R = (int) (GS_RED * R + GS_GREEN * G + GS_BLUE * B);

                // apply intensity level for sepid-toning on each channel
                R += (depth * red);
                if (R > 255) {
                    R = 255;
                }

                G += (depth * green);
                if (G > 255) {
                    G = 255;
                }

                B += (depth * blue);
                if (B > 255) {
                    B = 255;
                }

                // set new pixel color to output image
                bmOut.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));
            }
        }
        src.recycle();
        src = null;
        // return final image
        return bmOut;
    }
}
```

Here is createSepiaToningEffect() method is my filter to apply some effect on image but it will cause OutOfMemoryError.

I will solve the OutOfMemoryError using largeheap = true in manifests but i want better solution.

And it will take time when i call the filter and apply some effect on image.

Please give some solid solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html) is what google has to say about it:

> However, the ability to request a large heap is intended only for a
>   small set of apps that can justify the need to consume more RAM (such
>   as a large photo editing app). Never request a large heap simply
>   because you've run out of memory and you need a quick fix
>
> **Avoid wasting memory with bitmaps**
>
> When you load a bitmap, keep it in RAM only at the resolution you need
>   for the current device's screen, scaling it down if the original
>   bitmap is a higher resolution. Keep in mind that an increase in bitmap
>   resolution results in a corresponding (increase2) in memory needed,
>   because both the X and Y dimensions increase.

For better handling of images and memory give these developer recommendations a go:

[Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Also, would advise you to consider using some of Android Image Libraries for image manipulations and loading. E.g. Picasso, Fresco, Glide. Each has its own pros and cons. Choose what is right for you and suits your need best, below posts may guide you in the right direction.

[Picasso v/s Imageloader v/s Fresco vs Glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide)

[Comparison of Image Library for Android (Picasso, Fresco, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048629/comparison-of-image-library-for-android-picasso-fresco-etc)